# Adding Optionals/null safety to a nested flatMap/stream

Tags: java, java-stream, optional-chaining

I'm having trouble making my method null-safe using streams and flatMap..

My input is a `List<RequestSlot>`

And the objects are nested as such:

```
        Request
                OuterItem
                        List<InnerItem>
```

This is working to flatten the lists and create one List, but I'm unsure how to add Optionals here to make this null safe for each map/stream step.

```
  final List<InnerItem> innerItem = request.stream()
          .map(RequestSlot::getOuterItem)
          .flatMap(outerItem -> outerItem.getInnerItem().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have tried using Stream.ofNullable but that ends up creating a stream that I'm unsure how to then collect. Any pointers?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. It's not 100% clear what the problem is. Is it that `getOuterItem` and `getInnerItem` might both return `null`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't actually need to use `Optional`. Just `filter(Objects:nonNull)` everywhere after mapping to something that might be null. This filters out all the null things

```
// assuming request itself is not null
final List<InnerItem> innerItem = request.stream()
    .filter(Objects:nonNull) // list elements might be null
    .map(RequestSlot::getOuterItem) 
    .filter(Objects:nonNull) // outer item might be null
    .map(OuterItem::getInnerItem)
    .filter(Objects:nonNull) // inner items list might be null
    .flatMap(Collection::stream) // innerItemList -> innerItemList.stream()
    .filter(Objects:nonNull) // inner item list might contain nulls
    .toList();
```

If you really want to use `Stream.ofNullable`, use the pattern `flatMap(x -> Stream.ofNullable(x.getX()))` (where `getX` might return null).

```
final List<InnerItem> innerItem = request.stream()
    .filter(Objects:nonNull) // list elements might be null
    .flatMap(requestSlot -> Stream.ofNullable(requestSlot.getOuterItem())) // outer item might be null
    .flatMap(outerItem -> Stream.ofNullable(outerItem.getInnerItem())) // inner item list might be null
    .flatMap(Collection::stream) // innerItemList -> innerItemList.stream()
    .filter(Objects:nonNull) // inner item list might contain nulls
    .toList();
```

Comment: While more than often, `Optional` is unnecessary, it would make the code more concise in this case: `request.stream() .flatMap(r -> Optional.ofNullable(r) .map(RequestSlot::getOuterItem).map(OuterItem::getInnerItem) .map(Collection::stream).orElse(null)) .collect(Collectors.toList())` Though I would still question the design of a software with so many nullable components. Especially a method returning a list should never return `null`.